# Как импортировать csv файл в postgres и разбить его на несколько таблиц

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

я пытаюсь импортировать данные из scv в postgres с помощью psql на отдаленном ubuntu сервере и проблема в том что я не знаю как их разбить на 2 таблицы со связкой ManyToOne

Comment: А почему вы не хотите их импортировать во временную таблицу, а потом уже из неё заполнить другие?

Comment: Просто у меня 26 csv файлов больше чем на 60м транзакций и я думаю что если закинуть их в одну таблицу с 18-ию колонами потратит больше времени чем я хотел бы. Ну если не найдется другого варианта, то попробуй ваш вариант)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой вариант — это просто свалить все
данные в одну таблицу и разгрести оттуда отдельными
командами. Очень рекомендую этот вариант, если ресурсы
позволяют. Если нет, можно устроить адскую машинерию из вьюх,
триггеров, и прочего безобразия:

1. Предположим следующую схему из двух таблиц:

   ```sql
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t_1
   (
     t_1_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY
   )
   ;
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t_2
   (
     t_2_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY
   , t_1_id INTEGER REFERENCES t_1(t_1_id)
   , t_2_v  INTEGER
   )
   ;
   ```
2. Предположим следующий формат данных (*ID* 1 таблицы, *ID*
   2 таблицы, данные для 2 таблицы):

   ```csv
   1,1,101
   1,2,102
   2,3,201
   ```
3. Создаём вьюху:

   ```sql
   CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW t_1_and_t_2_view
       AS SELECT t_1.t_1_id, t_2.t_2_id, t_2.t_2_v
            FROM t_1 LEFT JOIN t_2
           USING (t_1_id);
   ```
4. Создаём функцию триггера:

   ```sql
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fill_t_1_and_t_2()
    RETURNS TRIGGER
   LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
         AS $$
            BEGIN
              INSERT INTO t_1 (t_1_id) VALUES (NEW.t_1_id)
                  ON CONFLICT (t_1_id) DO NOTHING;
              INSERT INTO t_2 (t_2_id, t_1_id, t_2_v)
              VALUES (NEW.t_2_id, NEW.t_1_id, NEW.t_2_v)
                  ON CONFLICT (t_2_id) DO NOTHING;
              RETURN NEW;
            END;
            $$;
   ```
5. Создаём триггер:

   ```sql
    CREATE TRIGGER t_1_and_t_2_view_insert_trigger
   INSTEAD OF INSERT ON t_1_and_t_2_view
       FOR EACH ROW
   EXECUTE FUNCTION fill_t_1_and_t_2(t_1_id, t_2_id, t_2_v);
   ```
6. Копируем:

   ```sql
   COPY t_1_and_t_2_view(t_1_id, t_2_id, t_2_v)
   FROM '/tmp/data.csv'
   WITH DELIMITER ',';
   ```
7. Долго думаем, стоит ли оно всё того :-) .

Фидель (очевидно не заработает на сайте,
ибо `COPY`):
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vY4Ho5jsaZG9iVx4oUqPrr/0.